# Plot digitization in MATLAB using ginput

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, axes, ginput

I'm trying to digitize this image using MATLAB:

[image: log scale plot]

I have the following script:

```
%// Get data from plot
clear all; close all;
%// Input
fname = 'Fig15a.PNG'; 
 xvec = [1e3:1:1e8]; 
 yvec = [1e-4:1:1e-1]; 
   xt = [1e3 1e4 1e5 1e6 1e7 1e8]; 
   yt = [1e-4 1e-3 1e-2 1e-1];

%// Read and plot the image
im = imread(fname);
figure(1), clf
im = im(end:-1:1,:,:);
image(xvec,yvec,im)
axis xy; 
grid on;

%// Set ticks
set(gca,'xtick',xt,'ytick',yt); %// Match tick marks

%// Collect data
[x,y] = ginput; %// Click on points, and then hit ENTER to finish

%// Plot collected data
hold on; plot(x,y,'r-o'); hold off;

%// Then save data as:
save Fig15a.mat x y
```

The script works fine
[image: Line scale output]

Is there a way I can change the `x` and `y` axes to a log scale ?
I have tried adding the following code in different places without luck:

```
%// Set Log scale on x and y axes
set(gca,'XScale','log','YScale','log');
```

Comment: Why do you not use existing tools for that? E.g. [this](http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you, did not know of existing tools. Followed my supervisor blindly in using MatLab :) would dough still out of curiosity know if this was possible in MatLab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below's a proof of concept that should get you on the right track. I have replaced things in your original code with what I consider "good practices".

```
function q36470836
%% // Definitions:
FIG_NUM = 36470836;
%% // Inputs:
fname = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2as4t.png'; 
xt = logspace(3,8,6);
yt = logspace(-4,-1,4);
%% // Init
figure(FIG_NUM); clf
% Read and plot the image
im = imread(fname);
hIMG = imshow(im); axis image;

%// Set ticks
hDigitizer = axes('Color','none',...
                  'XLim',[xt(1) xt(end)],'YLim',[yt(1) yt(end)],...
                  'XScale','log','YScale','log',...
                  'Position',hIMG.Parent.Position .* [1 1 696/785 (609-64+1)/609]);

uistack(hDigitizer,'top'); %// May be required in some cases
grid on; hold on; grid minor;

%// Collect data:
[x,y] = ginput; %// Click on points, and then hit ENTER to finish

%// Plot collected data:
scatter(x,y,'o','MarkerEdgeColor','r');

%// Save data:
save Fig15a.mat x y
```

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image: Output]

Few notes:

- `xt`, `yt` may be created in a cleaner fashion using [`logspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logspace.html).
- It is difficult (possibly impossible) to align the digitization grid with the image correctly, which would inevitably result in errors in your data. Though this can be helped in the following scenarios (for which you will require a vector graphics editor, such as the freeware [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/)):

  1. If, by any chance, you got this image from a PDF file, where it appears as a vector image (you can test this by zooming in as much as you like without the chart becoming pixelated; this *seems* to be your case from the way the `.png` looks), you would be better off saving it as a vector image and then you have two options:

     - Exporting the image to a bitmap with a *greatly* increased resolution and then attempting the digitization procedure again.
     - Saving the vector image as `.svg` then opening the file using your favorite text editor and getting the exact coordinates of the points.
  2. If the source image is a bitmap (as opposed to vector graphic), you can ["trace the bitmap"](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html), thus converting it to vectoric, then #GOTO step 1.
- This solution doesn't (currently) support resizing of the figure.
- The magic numbers appearing in the `Position` setting are scaling factors explained in the image below (and also `size(im)` is `[609 785 3]`). These can technically be found using "primitive image processing" but in this case I just hard-coded them explicitly.
  [image: Explanation of magic numbers]

Answer (score 0):

You can plot in double logarithmic scale with

```
loglog(x,y);
```

`help loglog` or the documentation give additional information.

For a single logarithmic scale use

```
semilogx(x,y);
semilogy(x,y);
```

Comment: My problem is not plotting on a loc scale but setting a loc scale when importing my image `image(xvec,yvec,im)`